# Heredar un VoidCallback en el mismo StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter

Estoy tratando de heredar un final VoidCallback requerido en el mismo Widget pero posteriormente, sin embargo el editor me marca un error al no conocer esta variable final aun cuando está en el mismo Widget, tal vez algo me está faltando.

```
class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {

  const LoginForm({Key? key, required this.onGoToForgot}) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback onGoToForgot;

  @override
  State<LoginForm> createState() => _LoginFormState();
}
```

Aquí es donde la quiero llamar pero no lo determina:

```
TextButton(
            child: const Text(
              'Olvidé contraseña',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 15,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: (){onGoToForgot;},  <<< Aqui marca error
          ),
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra el error _como texto, con formato_ que mencionas.

Answer (score 1):

La definición en el constructor es correcta, el error es al llamarlo, si es un `StatefulWidget` y tu estás en su `State`, debe ser así:

```dart
 onPressed: (){
   widget.onGoToForgot();
},
```

o versión simplicada:

```dart
onPressed: widget.onGoToForgot,
```